# protractor click specific element in repeater by binding

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, angularjs-ng-repeat, end-to-end

I know that question was asked in the past in some different forms, but still didn't find the exact answer.

I need to find an element inside a repeater and click it.
the repeater is a list of apps and I need to find specific app with attribute 'displayName' that equals to specific variable ("appName1" for example).

This is the repeater:

```
<div class="col-md-3 ng-scope" ng-repeat="app in userApps"> <a data-ui-sref="myAppById({appId:app.id})" class="square_container" href="/developers/myApps/ab7d4369-a2da-4bc5-92a5-a19a1af2db1d"> <strong class="app-display-name ng-binding">appName</strong>...
```

this is just a part.

I need to find app in userApps that it's displayName equals "appName1" for example and click it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to locate the desired element, though I would chain `element.all()` and `element()` and use [`by.xpath()` locator strategy](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.By.xpath):

```
var a = element.all(by.repeater("app in userApps")).element(by.xpath(".//a[strong = 'appName1']"));
a.click();
```

Or, using `filter()`:

```
element.all(by.repeater("app in userApps")).filter(function (elm) {
    return elm.evaluate("app.displayName").then(function (displayName) {
        return displayName === "appName1";
    });
}).then(function (elms) {
    var link = elms[0].element(by.tagName("a"));
    link.click();
});
```

Comment: thanks for answering. when trying that I get an error:  TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'element'

Comment: @user2880391 thanks for checking, what protractor version are you using? Try upgrading to the latest which would definitely support chaining element and element.all.

Comment: hey, I've upgraded to latest (2.0.0) and still get that error.

Comment: any idea? still facing that issue.

Comment: @user2880391 sure, how about the alternative in the updated answer?

Comment: it actually worked! thanks a lot! do you think there's a shorter way?

Comment: Has anyone got element.all().element() to work? or is the filter() the only way to make this work? if filter is the only possible way, can we remove the piece of this answer that does NOT work?   FYI I was able to make filter() work, but that feels skanky.